# Issue passing variable from javascript to controller Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, controller, variables

I'm struggling with this and just can't seem to make it work.
Need to pass the current users date (cdate) variable to my controller and in spite my alert windows shows the correct value, that value never reaches the controller.
Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#submit').click(function() {  
        var mydate=new Date()  
        var year=mydate.getYear()  
        if (year < 1000)  
            year+=1900  
        var day=mydate.getDay()  
        var month=mydate.getMonth()+1  
        var daym=mydate.getDate()  
        if (daym<10)  
            daym="0"+daym  
        if (month<10)  
            month="0"+month  
        var hours=mydate.getHours()  
        var minutes=mydate.getMinutes()  
        var seconds=mydate.getSeconds()  
        var cdate=+month+"/"+daym+"/"+year  
        $.post('user/available', {curdate: cdate});  
        alert(cdate);         
    });  
});
```

Controller:

```
$curdate=$this->input->post('curdate');
```

View:

```
echo form_open('user/available');  
echo form_input('dateav','',$dateav);  
input type="image" src="echo base_url();images/send.png" id="submit" alt="Submit button"   
echo form_close();
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: how did u include JQuery within CI? is manual or the CI way?

Comment: Have you checked if the request is really send properly? Check with FireBug if there is a POST request to user/available

Comment: @DRColossos  Strange i don't see the function being fired in firebug...

Comment: If the URL doesn't get requested, you know that something is either wrong with your code or jQuery is not properly loading. BTW, there are many `;` missing from your code, is this just a copy&paste thing or are there really semicolons missing?

Comment: Yes they are missing in the code. Will get that corrected. What's strange is that the alert window is being diplayed using IE but not when using chrome and firefox. And it was working yesterday just before i went to bed...

Comment: Ok what happening now is that i see the alert window and i see the the function in firebug but only for brief moments and then it refreshes, so i'm unable to see what's going on.. Any chance to tell me how can i stop it so i can see the function in firebug?

Comment: You are clicking an a form element and it redirects you to the target (action) of your form, add a `return false;` right after the alert to prevent the submission to the form target.

Comment: Just did a sleep(10) and i'm able to see what's happening.  
Right now cdate=7/12/2010 but what i get in the controller is curdate=7%2F12%2F2010 and that's why i'm not getting my strtotime working. how can i set it to 07/12/2010 in my controller?

Comment: decode it back ;) http://php.net/rawurldecode

Comment: Thanks. That didn't solve it. When i applied the return false; my controller stopped receiving the value and did nothing. When i remove return false; the controller works as expected(except for the date)...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to dump the whole request to stdout or something so you can see what URL is used and all the other parameters. Maybe there is a typo in the config.

[EDIT] The function should `return false`, otherwise Bad Things(TM) will happen (like the form will be posted twice and such).

If nothing happens but the alert showing up, then the `post()` call fails. [Read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and especially the part about error handling with [.ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

Comment: Hmmm, how can i do it? Sorry but i'm still a newbie :(.  
Thanks.

Comment: Just as DrColossos says: Use Firebug. If you see the alert, then Firebug must see the request. Note that Firebug must be running (open it and reload the page) and enabled for this page (check the prefs)!

Comment: Ok. What's happening right now is that i stopped seeing the alert window in chrome and firefox but i'm seeing in IE.  Has anyone experience this?  Using firebug i can's see the function being fired. How can i check it in IE?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for errors on Firefox. Rule: Make it work in FF (or Chrome) because they have the best developer support. Only when everything else works perfectly fine, try with IE.

Comment: @ Aaron. Ok. i'm doing that right now. I don't know what's going on but when i insert return false; right after the alert() the function gets an OK in firebug but it doesn't pass it to the controller it just sits there. If i remove return false; then the controller works but i get an error in firebug. Can anyone help me on this one. I just don't know what more to do and this is what's missing to finish the project :(

Comment: The function should return false, otherwise Bad Things(TM) will happen. See my edits for further instructions.

Comment: Ok. Will read the docs. Can you see my updated code? Is the view code ok?

Comment: Since i get an OK POST in firebug but nothing happens in the controller will .ajaxError() show something?

Comment: Did a little progress. Analyzing firebug POST HTML e found that my input field is not being filled and validation says the field is required=empty....So can someone please see my view code and tell me if my id="submit" is properly set?

Comment: Which input field isn't filled? Does that input field exist in the form? If not, what happens if you add it?

Comment: Hi Aaron, here's what i'm trying to do. The form has one field where the user selects a date(field is datepicker, a calendar appears and he selects a date). After that he submits the form. Together with that form i want to send the value of cdate(current users date) which is in the javascript code i posted. Then in the controller i make the calculations based on the dates provided(user can be in Australia and the dates be different).

Comment: Add an invisible field for `cdate`. It's possible that you can't post values for fields which don't exist in the form.

Comment: Ok added echo form_hidden('curdate',$cdate); but got an undefined error on the variable $cdate. How can i fill that variable with cdate value?

Comment: Ok I know i have to do a page reload in order to get that value. So now i'm trying to pass the value to the controller and then insert it back to the view.

Comment: What happens now is that when i click the datepicker field, the javascript triggers and i get and OK POST and i get another page on top of the page i had. Instead of just adding the from_hidden field, it adds the whole page again.Anyone had this before?

Comment: In that case, you must add a success handler to `post()`.

Comment: Ok. Can you send to an example on how to do it? Also i'm using .load because if i use .post nothing happens.

Comment: Unfortunately not since I'm not using Codeigniter. I suggest to follow an example in Codeigniter that is similar to your problem, make it work 100% as described in the docs and then start to modify it for your problem.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it's working now. Turns out i had to give full path to my ajax function on my controller. .load("user/ajax", data) didn't work so i had to create a var with the base_url() and then put like : .load(root+"user/ajax", data)   .